# MYSQL Out of Memory and Table Crashing

Tags: mysql, memory

A specific table in my database keeps crashing. I suspect it to be a bad buffer setting in the `my.conf` file, because it shows this error before crashing (most of the time it needs to be repaired):

```
18:26:59 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table './myDB/myTable.MYI'; try to repair it
18:54:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 59542644 bytes) 141020  
18:54:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Sort aborted
```

I don't think it is hard disk related, since `tmpdir` is set to `/tmp/` and has around 48 GB of free disk space.

**Input**

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';
```

**Output**

```
tmpdir         /tmp/
```

Here is a look at the `my.conf` settings. Take special note of the parameter `sort_buffer_size` which has been set way to high. However, I'm unsure if it will produce this kind of error when set too high. This machine runs Ubuntu with 8 GB RAM.

```
[mysqld]
max_connections         = 1500
back_log                = 50
skip-locking
key_buffer              = 819M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
table_cache             = 512 
sort_buffer_size        = 2048M
read_buffer_size        = 16M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size       = 16
query_cache_size        = 16M
thread_concurrency      = 8
max_heap_table_size     = 512M
wait_timeout            = 60
interactive_timeout     = 60
```

Any thoughts on this issue?

Comment: 2G sort buffer? That's crazy. Keep in mind, the sort buffer is *per session* buffer. There are plenty of sites that run well with 2M or less buffer.

Comment: Could you please use the formatting options in future?

Answer (score 1):

Set in config file this line

```
max_sort_length=8M
```

And happy day!

Comment: Can you edit your answer to provide a little more detail? Like, what this setting does and how that would address the problem? Perhaps link to some documentation? More complete answers are preferred here. Thanks!